# CMake, MinGW=Undefined Reference to GetIpAddrTable-> iphlpapi.h

Tags: c++, windows, qt, cmake, mingw

I have a CMake project that works pretty good in Linux, but it doesn't under Windows.
The first issue comes by final linking:

```
[100%] Linking CXX shared library libProjlib.dll
CMakeFiles\Projlib.dir/objects.a(configserver.cpp.obj): In function `ConfigServer::findAdapter(unsigned long*)':
C:/Users/jose/Documents/git-Projects/Proj/Projlib/configserver.cpp:859: undefined reference to `GetIpAddrTable'
Error 1
```

**findAdapter belongs to C:\Qt\Tools\mingw810_64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\iphlpapi.h**, but doesn't link automatic

My project is missconfigured, I think. *I would like to select the MinGW compiler, automatic through CMakeLists.txt (For now, I configure the compiler means cmake-gui.exe ..), and naturally fix the issue*, but I don't know how. (Google didn't gave me a solution)

Please, any help or suggestion, link.. etc. will be wellcomed.

Here is my CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
set(CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME "testProject")
project(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME})

set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)

if("Windows" STREQUAL "${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME}")
    message(STATUS "_______________________________________Compiling on Windows")

elseif("Linux" STREQUAL "${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME}")
    message(STATUS "_______________________________________Compiling on GNU/Linux :-)")
endif()


set(CMAKE_BUILD_PARALLEL_LEVEL 8)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

#list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/home/enigma/Qt/5.15.2/gcc_64") #linux
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "C:\\Qt\\Tools\\mingw810_64")
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON) 
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

message(STATUS "___________________________________________________${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}")
if(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL "Debug")
    set(binPath "binDebugProj")
elseif()
    set(binPath "binProj")  
endif()

set(TMP_BUILD "tmpBuild")
set(Proj_LIB "Projlib")


add_subdirectory(${Proj_LIB} "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../${binPath}/${TMP_BUILD}/${Proj_LIB}")
include_directories(${Proj_LIB})
```

Comment: GetIpAddrTable requires linking of Iphlpapi.lib.

Comment: Ok is a shared windows library, but why doesn't come automatic? How should I do? Thanks in advance

Comment: My Question could be seen as trivial, but: target_link_libraries($Project_LIB} PUBLIC Qt5::Core Qt5::Network iphlpapi)  didn't work.  Naturally, The code have the respective includes #include <iphlpapi.h>

Comment: On Stack Overflow we don't manually add "SOLVED" or other mark which indicates that the problem is solved. The question will automatically be marked such when it has accepted answer. You may even accept your own answer, but with some delay.

Answer (score 0):

The Solution is:
target_link_libraries(${CARDEA_LIB} PUBLIC Qt5::Core Qt5::Network iphlpapi)

At the end did work. (I was savin in anoter CMakeLists.txt AGGHH, too musch hours today)